# Console not printing anything?

Tags: java

I'm having a problem whenever I run this it just doesn't print anything. I'm getting no errors and still it just prints nothing. I can't even type in it. What is going on, please help. I have been working on this for a few days trying to fix the errors that there were at the start and now after fixing when I try and run it. It just doesn't say anything. I have never seen this before so please someone help me

```
public class Mac {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

    }

    public Mac()
    {
       intArrayExample();
       stringArrayExample();
       intArrayExample2();
       stringArrayExample();
   }


   private void intArrayExample()
   {
      int[] intArray = new int[3];
      intArray[0] = 1;
      intArray[1] = 2;
      intArray[2] = 3;
      System.out.println("Numerical Listing");
      for (int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++)
      {
          System.out.println(intArray[i]);
      }
   }

   private void stringArrayExample()
   {
      String[] stringArray = new String[3];
      stringArray[0] = "a";
      stringArray[1] = "b";
      stringArray[2] = "c";
      System.out.println("Alphabetical Listing");
      for (int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println(stringArray[i]);
      }
   }


   private void intArrayExample2()
   {
      int[] intArray = new int[] {4,5,6,7,8};
      System.out.println("Numerical Listing (version 2)");
      for (int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++)
      {
        System.out.println(intArray[i]);
      }
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   private void stringArrayExample1()
   {
      String[] stringArray = new String[3];
      stringArray[0] = "d";
      stringArray[1] = "h";
      stringArray[2] = "e";
      stringArray[3] = "f";
      System.out.println("Alphabetical Listing (version 2)");
      for (int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println(stringArray[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not printing anything because your main method is empty.

Comment: how is this a [tag:compiler-error]?

Comment: make all your methods `static` type and call `Mac()` from your `main` method

Answer (score 1):

Your main method `public static void main(String[]args)` is empty! Nothing is being executed! You shoud write`Mac mac = new Mac();`, doing this, will call all the methods in the constructor:

```
public Mac()
{
    intArrayExample();
    stringArrayExample();
    intArrayExample2();
    stringArrayExample();
}
```